# Need a little feedback about my database design, pretty straightforward

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm going to allow companies to register on my website and create job listings.

I'm currently approaching the problem by creating a Company table with Name, Logo and Password fields. Then when a person registers he can say, "I belong to X company"; at this point, I'll request the password written in by the initial registrator. If she/he enters the correct password then he is given permission to create job postings in the name of the company.

**Why I'm doing things this way:**
If I just put everything inside of the Company table, every new user would have to create an account and I'll have redundant information, CompanyName, Logo, etc.

And if I do things without a password, anyone can post a job opening under a companies name and that's just wrong.

Care to share some input? Am I doing things wrong? How would **you** do it?

Comment: It's a pretty basic decision, do you really need input on such trivialities?

Comment: A company can have more than one user, correct?

Comment: @Kris: Yes, a company will probably have more than one employee posting things.

Comment: ...and every job could be 'followed' by many employees? or all the  employees of a certain company can follow (for follow i mean see, edit or delete) all the company jobs?

Comment: No, each employee is only able to post jobs in their own companies name. And they cannot edit each others posts, regardless if they are from the same company.

Comment: How do you make sure the initial registrar is actually working for the company he just created and not just some kid posing as a company manager for Microsoft?

Comment: That's a good question. How do you recommend I handle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do "jobs requests" like Facebook's friend requests and if the user really work in that company, the company manager just has to login and confirm it.

Comment: The user who creates a 'company' could be the 'manager' for that company. If than another user says he belongs to that company, the manager should confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

[Database Normalization.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Create a separate Users and Companies table. Can one user post for multiple companies? if so, you need a many-to-many relationship (which requires a third table to keep track of the relationships). Otherwise, a one-to-many should work.

Comment: Just as a side-note: it could be done even with just 1 table, with all the company and users fields; the company row will have the 'company fields' filled and the users fields empty and viceversa. But this will require to self-joinig the table to itself everytime.

Comment: @DaNieL  I think this will create redundancy, this will not be a normalized solution and cant be scalable in future

Answer (score 0):

You should create two tables:

```
Company:
 - id
 - logo
 ( - name, etc )

User
 - id
 - companyId (foreign key to Company.id )
 - password
 ( - username, etc. )
```

This way a User is a child of a Company identified by companyId. Now, if a user logs in, you can identify what company s/he belongs to by finding the Company corresponding with the companyId. Now you have a password per user, and a company per user.

And like Jimmy says, if you need Users to be able to be part of more Company's you would get:

```
Company
 - id
 - logo

User
 - id
 - password

Company_User
 - companyId (foreign key to Company.id )
 - userId (foreign key to User.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should create table like

Employers:

```
     eid(pk)
     logo
     Username
     Password
     profile
     etc....
```

JobSeekers:

```
    jid(pk)
    Username
    Password
    etc...
```

JobPosts:

```
   id(pk)
   eid(Fk to Employers.eid)
   JobTitle
   Specifications....
```